# Is it moral for humans to procreate?

Tags: ethics

I know it's in our nature and that we want to have kids so that humanity can continue. But **is it moral** to continue bringing kids into a world that's dying and is full of evil and hate? I feel having kids is purely selfish and this is coming from a person who has a child.

Comment: Welcome. It's best for answers to be as objective as possible. I think there's a good question here but as phrased it invites subjective opinions. So I'm suggesting an edit.

Comment: The question should be specified to ask for morality within a certain philosophical framework, otherwise the question will be too broad. Consider that the answers for e.g. deontological, virtue-based, utilitarian or pragmatistic moral systems can vary.

Comment: Are talking about your parents or mine?  :)  Seriously, do you think a world in which everybody refused to procreate would be a better world than the one we have now?  Do you really think the world ever changes, morally?  It's no better and no worse than it ever was or ever will be.

Comment: _Antinatalism_ and _natalism_ are the two philosophical positions dealing precisely with this topic, and reaching opposing conclusions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antinatalism for an overview and a list of authors.

Comment: I think this was unjustly marked as opinion based. Anyway, I hope you find this helpful: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/parenthood/#MorPro